# Magento2: frontend event is not working (sales_order_place_after)

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, magento-2.0.2

I am catching `sales_order_place_after` event in `etc/adminhtml/events.xml` everything working fine..

But same is not working while trying to catch in `etc/frontend/events.xml`.
also tried to catch the event in `etc/events.xml` but no luck..

In brief my problem is:

`sales_order_place_after` **event is working while placing the order from admin Dashboard but same is not working if order placed from frontend.**

is there any different way to call this event from front end ??

**adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_grid_vendors" instance="Company\Vendors\Observer\Adminhtml\Vendor\AddVendorSalesOrders" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_grid_vendors_customer" instance="Company\Vendors\Observer\AddVendorOrders" />
    </event>
</config>
```

observers:
**Observer/Adminhtml/Vendor/AddVendorSalesOrders.php**

```
namespace Company\Vendors\Observer\Adminhtml\Vendor;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AddVendorSalesOrders implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
        die('mujassam');
      }
}
```

**Observer/AddVendorOrders.php**

```
namespace Company\Vendors\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AddVendorOrders implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
        die('mujassam');
      }
}
```

Comment: Did try deleting `var/cache` and `var/generation` after your changes ? Because this event is widely used in Magento 2 original code so it should work the way you described it. Please post your full `events.xml`

Comment: Can u please share your code`etc/frontend/events.xml`

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i tried clearing all the cache/genration but no luck, I have edited the question with events.

Comment: @MohammadMujassam could you post both admin and frontend observers please ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism sure, edited the question.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have doubt if this event is available for global use, I mean this event is not triggering in front end.. any idea ??

Comment: @MohammadMujassam this event is definitely available for global use, you can check `Magento/Sales/etc/events.xml`, the first event in this file is the `sales_order_place_after` event I'm not quite sure what's wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your support.. this is how I did catch the event..

**Company/Vendors/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_grid_vendors_customer" instance="Company\Vendors\Observer\AddVendorOrders" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Instead of placing your event in `Company/Vendors/etc/frontend/events.xml`, place it in `Company/Vendors/etc/events.xml`

Comment: Thank you good sir! I spent the past 6+ hours trying to figure out why the observer was not working. I had it in the `etc/frontend` directory.

Answer (score 3):

In case you do *not* want to listen to the `sales_order_place_after` event globally, the correct scope would be `webapi_rest` instead of `frontend`.

Answer (score -1):

> CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="YourName" cacheable="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**cacheable="false"**

add this now you event is working

Comment: the answer is not relevant to original question