# Checkout saveOrder() function

Tags: magento2, php, onepage-checkout

> I want to do something after customer does the checkout. I found code like
>   below from

**`vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php`**

```
public function saveOrder()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $isNewCustomer = false;
        switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
            case self::METHOD_GUEST:
                $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
                break;
            case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
                $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
                $isNewCustomer = true;
                break;
            default:
                $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
                break;
        }
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($this->getQuote());
        if ($isNewCustomer) {
            try {
                $this->_involveNewCustomer();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_checkoutSession
            ->setLastQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
            ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
            ->clearHelperData();

        if ($order) {
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
                ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote()]
            );

            /**
             * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
             */
            $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
            /**
             * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
             */
            if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                try {
                    $this->orderSender->send($order);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->critical($e);
                }
            }

            // add order information to the session
            $this->_checkoutSession
                ->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
                ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
                ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId())
                ->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_submit_all_after',
            [
                'order' => $order,
                'quote' => $this->getQuote()
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

> Is it true that the function above for saving the order when customer
>   doing checkout? I tried to add some SQL query inside to save data to
>   my custom table, but when I tried to do the checkout, the SQL doesn't
>   run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried in wrong place. Try following location.

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php
```

In

```
public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if ($paymentMethod) {
        $paymentMethod->setChecks([
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT,
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY,
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY,
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX,
            \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL,
        ]);
        $quote->getPayment()->setQuote($quote);

        $data = $paymentMethod->getData();
        $quote->getPayment()->importData($data);
    }

    if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() === self::METHOD_GUEST) {
        $quote->setCustomerId(null);
        $quote->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
        $quote->setCustomerIsGuest(true);
        $quote->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    }

    $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_before', ['quote' => $quote]);

    $order = $this->submit($quote);

    if (null == $order) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.')
        );
    }

    $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());

    $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_all_after', ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote]);
    return $order->getId();
}
```

**Don't modify core file. Use plugin/observer/overwrite for changing behaviour.**

Comment: Why should i dont modify the core? And what is the event name for before saving the order/checkout?

Comment: Why should i dont modify the core? -> because when you update magento version then your modification will be gone.

Comment: And what is the event name for before saving the order/checkout? –> In your case you use plugin (aroundPlaceOrder).

Comment: One more thing, im modified the checkout page with adding datepicker, how could i get the value inside the datepicker from observer?

Comment: If i used plugin (aroundPlaceOrder), will it effect the multishipping checkout too?

Comment: In this case https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date will help you. Also As i know, this type of question already available in SE.

Comment: Check for saving into db https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110906/call-to-a-member-function-getaccountno-on-null-magento-2

Comment: Hellow @RohelRana could you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197710/cant-get-datepicker-value-from-custom-checkout-page ?

Answer (score 1):

Best way : you need to use event **sales_order_place_after** to add something after customer does the checkout.

to add event and observer follow below steps.

etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_grid_vendors_customer" instance="Company\Vendors\Observer\AddVendorOrders" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/AddVendorOrders.php

```
namespace Company\Vendors\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AddVendorOrders implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
        die('test'); // write your code here
      }
}
```

For more information please see below links

### [Magento2: frontend event is not working (sales_order_place_after)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112825/magento2-frontend-event-is-not-working-sales-order-place-after)

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

Comment: Hello vaibhav. How are you?  plz open once http://rojudeal.in/Beta/  when i am trying to checkout as guest or anyway, i cant go to shipping. check once brother

Comment: On click of Continue You can see there is any Warning in ajax console: A non-numeric value encountered  in /home/himarojudeal/public_html/Beta/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you. to clear this issue, what should i do please tell?

Comment: are you using some costume shipping method ? may be there is issue on value that pass to _getPerorderPrice . I could not say any thing as of now you have to check it on your own

Comment: yeah working. but registration is not working at checkout. But normal registration and login and checkout as guest also  working