# Can't get datepicker value from custom checkout page

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, onepage-checkout, datepicker

Im following this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110906/call-to-a-member-function-getaccountno-on-null-magento-2) to get datepicker value on my custom checkout page.
Here is my code below.

**Test/Show/etc/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="customaddorder" instance="Test\Show\Observer\CustomSaveOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Test/Show/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="ship_date" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Test/Show/Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Show\Model\Checkout;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $shipDate = $extAttributes->getShipDate();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setShipDate($shipDate);
    }
}
```

**Test/Show/Observer/CustomSaveOrder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Show\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomSaveOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager)
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        // $order->setAccountNo( $quote->getAccountNo() );

        $objectManagers = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManagers->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('show_test');

        $cartId = $order->getQuoteId();
        $allItems = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        $ship = $quote->getShipDate();
        $add = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();

        foreach ($allItems as $value) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (cart_id, prod_id, qty, add_id, ship, sku) VALUES ('".$cartId."','".$value->getProductId()."','" .$value->getQty(). "','".$add."','".$ship."','".$value->getSku()."')";
            $connection->query($sql);
        }

        $allItemsQuery = "SELECT id FROM " .$tableName. " WHERE cart_id = " .$cartId;
        $getAllItems = $connection->fetchAll($allItemsQuery);

        foreach ($getAllItems as $contain) {
            $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO order_list (order_id, item_id) VALUES ('" .$order->getId(). "','" .$contain['id']."')";
            $connection->query($queryInsert);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Test/Show/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="additional_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Test_Show/js/view/custom-checkout</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Test/Show/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-checkout.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';
    var show_hide_custom_blockConfig = window.checkoutConfig.show_hide_custom_block;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Test_Show/view/frontend/templates/custom-checkout'
        },
        canVisibleBlock: show_hide_custom_blockConfig
    });
});
```

**Test/Show/view/frontend/web/template/view/custom-checkout.html**

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Date'" data-role="title"></div>
        <div>
        <br>
            <input style="width: 150px;" data-bind="datepicker: true" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" id="calendar_inputField" name="ship_date" aria-required="true" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>



<script>
     require([
          "jquery",
          "mage/calendar"
     ], function($){
         $("#calendar_inputField").calendar({
         });
       });
</script>
```

**Test/Show/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Test_Show/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

**Test/Show/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js**

```
/*global define,alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            ship_date: $('[name="ship_date"]').val()
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

I tried to debug, and i still get the value at `ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php`, but i can't get the value at `CustomSaveOrder.php`, is there something missing at my code?

Comment: Did you created ship_date column in quote table?

Comment: No im not, should i create it first?

Comment: Yes, create column first, clear cache. Then it should work.

Comment: Yes it's all works, thank you so much for your help.